# Can I use Copernicus Land Services data on Open Data Cube?

Tags: land-use, open-data-cube, indexing

I need to use Copernicus Land services data (that I can take from the official website of Copernicus land: https://land.copernicus.eu/) on Open Data Cube.

How can I do it?

How can I index this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions to ask are:

1. Is the data directly accessible as Cloud Optimised GeoTIFFs through a public http API?
2. Does the data have Spatio-Temporal Asset Catalog metadata?

If these two are true, then it's pretty easy to index the data and use it in the Open Data Cube. If not, you might need to either create metadata on the fly as you index, or convert the data to COGs and store it somewhere with metadata.

Comment: Okok, I understand! Thank you very much for the help!